# Using loops in R to iterate through two columns for lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm using lubridate to compare the intervals between a number of time intervals e.g.

```
firstdate <- 2015-01-02 00:42
nextdate <- 2015-01-02 07:19
difftime(nextdate, firstdate, units = "hours")
>Time difference of 397 mins
```

However, I have two columns in a csv file with 240+ dates that I would like to iterate through and compare the interval times between the dates.

I was looking at looping in R. As a simple test, I added four values to two columns in a data frame and tried the following:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("2015-01-02 07:19", "2015-01-02 07:19", "2015-01-19 18:51","2015-01-26 03:40")
                ,col2 = c("2015-01-02 07:50", "2015-01-02 09:20", "2015-01-19 19:00", "2015-01-26 06:05"))

for(i in 1:4)
  {
  difftime(df$col2[i], df$col1[i], units = "hours")
  }
```

However, the code doesn't generate any output. I'm wondering, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you change the command inside of the loop to `print(difftime(df$col2[i], df$col1[i], units = "hours"))`, you will get output. Hoever, you should not solve this problem with a for loop. It 's better to do something like `df <- transform(df, diff = difftime(col2, col1, units = "hours"))`.

Comment: I think the main thing to learn here is that `difftime` can handle vectors, so there is no need to iterate over each element. Therefore, you can remove the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, yes I heard that loops are discouraged in r and as you both mention there are ways to acomplish this task without loops. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you. I use an apply function to just make sure that the dates and times are in the right format

```
library(lubridate)

df <- cbind(col1 = c("2015-01-02 07:19", "2015-01-02 07:19", "2015-01-19 18:51","2015-01-26 03:40")
                 ,col2 = c("2015-01-02 07:50", "2015-01-02 09:20", "2015-01-19 19:00", "2015-01-26 06:05"))

df<-as.data.frame(apply(df,2,function(x)strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")))

difftime(df[,1],df[,2],units = "hours")

Time differences in hours
[1] -0.5166667 -2.0166667 -0.1500000
[4] -2.4166667
```